# Is there any way of finding the solution of $8^k\equiv a \pmod{ 2a+1}$ such that $a$ and $k$ are both positive integers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

My recent result pointed on two cases, one of which requires an integer solution to
$8^k\equiv a \pmod{ 2a+1}.$

Specifically I am interested to know as to what values of $k$ it is possible or more interesting, what values of $k$ it would make the expression impossible.

It is conjecture that, the expression always have solution when $k=21$.

No solutions exist at $k=1$ and $k=5$.

Any help would be very important to me.

Answer (score 3):

Another way of writing this is that you want:

$$2^{3k+1}\equiv -1\pmod{2a+1}$$

or you want a factor $d$ of $2^{3k+1}+1$. (Any such factor is necessarily odd, giving $a=\frac{d-1}{2}$.) This gives all solutions.

**Trivial solutions**:

> The case when $d=1$ gives $a=0$ and a trivial relationship:
>   $$8^k\equiv 0\pmod{1}$$
>   The case $d=2^{3k+1}+1$ gives $a=8^k$ and thus:
>   $$8^k\equiv 8^k\pmod{2\cdot 8^k+1}$$

The non-trivial solutions arise from non-trivial $d\mid 2^{3k+1}+1$.

If there are no non-trivial values for $a$, then $2^{3k+1}+1$ is prime.

If $2^{j}+1$ is prime, then $j$ is a power of $2$. And the cases when $3k+1=2^n$ requires $n$ to be even, so you to find $n$ so that $F_{2n}=2^{2^{2n}}+1$, where $F_k$ is the $n$th [Fermat numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number).

So if $k$ yields only trivial solutions, then  $k=\frac{F_{2n}-1}{3}$ for some $n$ where $F_{2n}$ is prime.

Unfortunately, the question of whether there is any $k>4$ such that $F_k$ is prime is unknown.

The reason then that $k=5$ has no (non-trivial) solution is that $F_{4}$.

Unfortunately, not much is actually known about what  $F_{2n}=2^{4^n}+1$ are prime. We know that $F_6$ is is divisible by $274177$, so $a=137088$ solves for $k=\frac{4^3-1}{3}=21$.

We know that $F_{8}$, $F_{10}$, and $F_{12}$ are not primes. So if there is a $k>5$ with no nontrivial $a$, it must be at least $\frac{2^{14}-1}{3}=5461.$

**Nontrivial solutions**

There are non-trivial solutions in all other cases. If $3k+1=bc$ where $b$ is odd, then:
$$2^{3k+1}+1=\left(2^{c}+1\right)\left(2^{c(b-1)}-2^{c(b-2)}+\cdots -2^{c}+1\right)\tag{*}$$

So we always have a solution in these cases where $a$ is a power of $2$, namely $a=2^{c-1}$. You could also use the right factor of $(*)$ for $d$, of course.

These are not the only solutions. You have to find all divisors of $2^{3k+1}+1$ to find all such $a$.

**Specific examples:**

When $k=2$, we have that $2^{3k+1}+1=129=3\cdot 43$ and you get that:

$$8^k\equiv 1\pmod{2\cdot 1+1}\\
8^k\equiv 21\pmod{2\cdot 21+1}$$

When $k=3$, then $2^{10}+1=1025=5^2\cdot 41$. So the non-trivial factors are $d=5,25,41,5\cdot 41$ giving $a=2,12,20,102.$

The case of $k=7$ is the smallest with $6$ non-trivial values $a$, because:

$$2^{22}+1=5\cdot 397 \cdot 2113$$

---

**For what value of $a$ does $k$ exists?**

Given $a$, when does $k$ exist? We need, when $d=2a+1$, that: $2^{3k+1}\equiv-1\pmod{d}$. This in turn means that the order of $2$ modulo $d$ must be even and not a multiple of $3$.

If the order of $2$ modulo $d$ is $\alpha$, with $\alpha=6n+2$, then:

$$2^{3n+1}\equiv -1\pmod{d}$$ and thus $k=n$ is the smallest solution, and $3k+1=(3n+1)(6m+1)$ is the general solution (or $k=6nm+2m+n$.)

If the order of $2$ modulo $d$ is $6n+4$, then:

$$2^{3n+2}\equiv -1\pmod{d}$$

and hence you need $3k+1=(3n+2)(6m+5)$ or $k=6nm+5n+4m+3.$ The smallest is $k=5n+3$.

But if $\alpha\not\equiv 2,4\pmod{6}$ then there is no such $k$ for the given $a$.

Comment: I am very much happy for the response but may I ask further: Is there any solutions for k that will make the relation true? If yes what are these solutions? I understand that we cannot know what k's that will make the relation false because it will ask for fermat primes.

Comment: If $d\mid 2^{3k+1}+1$ then $a=\frac{d-1}{2}$ gives such a solution. Indeed, this gives all solutions. In particular, if $3k+1$ has an odd factor $m$, then $2^{(3k+1)/m}+1\mid 2^{3k+1}+1$, so we get $a=2^{(3k+1-m)/m}$.

Answer (score 2):

As Thomas Andrews’s reformulation shows, the question is equivalent to asking about the factorization of $2^{3k+1}+1$. Besides the fact that this expression is divisible by 3 whenever $k$ is even, there is a more “interesting” situation when the exponent $3k + 1$ is also of the form $4j + 2$; i.e. when it is of the form $12h+10$. Then the expression takes the form $2^{12h + 10} + 1 = (2^{6h + 5} - 2^{3h + 3} + 1)(2^{6h + 5} + 2^{3h + 3} + 1)$. This is an example of an [Aurifeuillian factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurifeuillean_factorization).